# Use sed command along with readlink (or simmilar) to replace full path into text

Tags: bash, sed

I'm writing a BASH script in which I want to use `sed` to replace the fullpath of a file into a text.

I currently have this:

```
Path= readlink -e /home/user/Videos/*.mp4
sed -i "s/original_text/$Path/g" /home/user/Documents/Text.txt
```

The idea is to replace the path of a single MP4 video (there aren't other videos in that folder) into a text file so I don't have to write the name of the video every time I want to replace it.

I have tried different options for this problem but I can't make it work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use command substitution to save the output of a command in a variable:

```
Path="$(readlink -e /home/user/Videos/*.mp4)"
```

Also the shell does not support any space(s) around `=` while declaring variables.

---

If you have multiple files, better use an array:

```
Paths=( $(readlink -e /home/user/Videos/*.mp4) )
```

and access the array elements by `"${Paths[@]}"`

Answer (score 1):

I believe that your `$Path` has `slash(/)` in value, e.g. `/home/user/Videos/foo.mp4`, this will make your `sed` fail. You can use other delimiter for sed's `s` command.

Try this sed line:

```
sed -i "s@original_text@$Path@g" /home/user/Documents/Text.txt
```

also you should quote your `readlink` command, and remove the space right after `=`